# WPF graph from collection using only XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have an XmlDataProvider with a node for a graph:

```
<Nums SegmentWidth="20">
    <Sample Val="3" />
    <Sample Val="12" />
    <Sample Val="3" />
    <Sample Val="103" />
    <Sample Val="9" />
</Nums>
```

So the first node will be 0,3, second 20,12 etc.
I have a task to draw a simple graph with lines using only XAML (no C# or external libraries allowed).
So, I need some kind of loop here, to draw lines, where

X1 = SegmentWidth * (current - 1)

Y1 = Val[current]

X2 = SegmentWidth * current

Y2 = Val[current+1]

The problem is how to do this math in XAML using data binding. Any ideas?

Comment: Investigate [XAML Path Markup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx) syntax.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a canvas and then just draw the lines but this requires some work.

Comment: I think you need to show him a little bit of code to get him started.

Comment: The problem here that i need to use data from [i] and [i+1] to draw a line. And also, I have to increase x by SegmentWidth each time.